# Select into and Join Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, select-into

My problem stems from this:

[VBA (Excel) vs SQL - Comparing values in two rows (loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420983/vba-excel-vs-sql-comparing-values-in-two-rows-loop)

I've modified the script a tad and it looks like this:

```
;WITH data AS 
( 
   SELECT a.i, a.M, b.M as NextM, 
   CASE WHEN a.M = 65 AND b.M = 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS shouldIncreaseQ   
   FROM MyTable a       
   LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable b      
   ON a.i + 1 = b.i 
), test as
(
   SELECT data.M, data.NextM, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM data AS ref 
   WHERE ref.shouldIncreaseQ = 1 AND ref.i <= data.i) as Q FROM data 
)
```

So now lets select * from test.  I get something that looks like this.

```
M      NextM     Q
65     65        1
65     65        1
65     120       2
120    63        2
65     120       3
120    NULL      3
```

NOW.. all I want to is take the Q column (where Q pertains to the NextM) and put that in my original mytable.

So something like this:

```
i     M      Q
1     65     1
2     65     1
3     120    2
4     63     2
5     120    3
6     55     3
```

I hope that makes sense.  I have been playing with select into, and even insert into all DAY (literally hours) with no luck. (using every type of join you can imagine)

Thank you in advance.  (also can someone tell me how to make my tables look nicer.. do you use html to do it or what)?

UPDATE:

```
;WITH data AS 
 ( 
   SELECT a.i, a.M, b.M as NextM, 
   CASE WHEN a.M = 65 AND b.M = 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS shouldIncreaseQ   
   FROM MyTable a       
   LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable b      
   ON a.i + 1 = b.i 
 ), 
test as
(
   SELECT data.i, data.M, data.NextM, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM data AS ref 
   WHERE ref.shouldIncreaseQ = 1 AND ref.i <= data.i) as Q FROM data 
),
final as
(
   select a.i, a.M as zw_step,  b.Q as prodid
   from test a
   left outer join test b
   on a.i - 1 = b.i
)

SELECT final.i, final.zw_step, final.prodid
FROM final
```

Now.. the select statement is how I like it.  EXCEPT the darn thing will not work with a insert into command.. (you might have to fool around with final). 
I'm now afraid of CTE, I will probably never use them again this.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: What does mytable look like? Does it already contain the column Q?

Comment: @Josien mytable can contain column Q but the values would be all null.  I figured out away to do this with an insert into...however another problem occurs.. I have a good select statement but as soon as i put insert into in front it won't insert properly.  It just adds to the last row instead of linking to the proper i value.  I'll post my code in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly what you are looking for. But you might want to replace

```
SELECT final.i, final.zw_step, final.prodid
FROM final;
```

with

```
UPDATE MT
  SET MT.Q = F.prodid
  FROM MyTable AS MT
  INNER JOIN final AS F ON MT.i = F.i AND MT.M = F.zw_step;
```

This will replace the values in column `Q` in `MyTable` with the values in column `prodid` in `final`. Is this what you're trying to do? (Based on "NOW.. all I want to is take the Q column (where Q pertains to the NextM) and put that in my original mytable.")